# Ведение логов из нескольких файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x

При такой настройке у меня логируется только один файл:

```
logging.basicConfig(format=u'%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    filename=os.path.join('logs', __name__))
```

Как настроить логер так, чтобы логи писались для нескольких файлов и для каждого файла был свой файл с логами ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [книгой рецептов по логированию](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook)

В упрощенном варианте: создавайте отдельный лог для каждой Вашей задачи/модуля/логической структуры

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Пример:

```
import logging

logger = {}
logger['warning'] = logging.getLogger('MYWARNING')
logger['error'] = logging.getLogger('MYERROR')

logger['warning'].warning("Warning log!")
logger['error'].error("Error log!")
```

Comment: Это не работает. Если сделать так, то логи будут записываться в первом указанном в `getLogger`e имени.

Comment: Так используйте список и создайте несколько экземпляров логирования. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: Покажите на примере о чем вы говорите.

Comment: Показал в ответе.

Comment: mywarning, myerror это плохой вводящий в заблуждение пример. Лучше имена типа `django.request`, `myproject.custom` использовать. Чтобы каждый logger писал в свой отдельный файл, им нужно FileHandler настроить (отдельный для каждого logger). [Конфигурацию можно словарём задавать](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#an-example-dictionary-based-configuration) или из ini файла читать.

Comment: Плохой почему? Лучше чем что? Чем лучше? Нет никаких весомых оснований для именования. К примеру я использую отдельную строку форматирования, в которой отдельная переменная выводит в лог имя модуля, генерирующего событие. Считаю такую практику полезной.

Comment: LONG_LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - [%(name)s.%(levelname)s] [%(threadName)s, %(module)s.%(funcName)s@%(lineno)d] %(message)s'